# AngularJS - JQuery News Ticker - After moving news the javascript function doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-plugins

This is an awkward problem, which will be better explained by looking at the live demo. Basically I have a news box populated with ng-repeat using Angular. Then I am using a jquery plugin called news ticker which allows the news headlines to move around. The first time you land on the page the news items are in their proper spots and they call the function accordingly. After moving them up or down, they stop calling the function, set a breakpoint in the code and after moving the breakpoint is never hit.

***Edit*** - After researching this further I have found that it is because the elements need to be compiled using $compile after they're re added. However following some examples I have not gotten this to work. I need a way of compiling after a move event with this plugin.

Live [demo](http://ssiclouddev.azurewebsites.net/)

Angular Script for with function that should be called.

```
$scope.UpdateNews = function (item,number) {
            console.log(item + ' ' + number);
            switch (item)
            {
                case 'General':
                    $scope.NewsCast.General.Body = $scope.News.GeneralNews[number].Text;
                    break;
            }
        };
```

What the HTML looks like with the news boxes

```
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-jQuery-News-Ticker-Plugin-with-Bootstrap-3-Bootstrap-News-Box/scripts/jquery.bootstrap.newsbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt logo-inverse pull-left"></span><b> General News</b></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <ul class="demo1" style="overflow-y: hidden; height: 280px;" ng-model="Idk">
                                <li style="" class="news-item text-left" ng-repeat="item in News.GeneralNews"><strong>{{item.DateValue | date: "MMM dd yyyy"}}</strong> {{item.Preview}}<a class="FakeClickable" ng-click="UpdateNews('General',item.index)" data-target="#GeneralModal" data-toggle="modal">Read more...</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div ng-if="Width>768">
                                <div ng-include="'../pages/Modals/General/GENERAL_INLINE.html'"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Do  you solved it?

Comment: Nope I eventually made my own ish component for it